# How can i extract compressed .cmpr file ? (application/x-compress)

Tags: linux, compression, tar, gunzip

Been trying so hard, searched the entire internet, barely even found some reference to this kind of compression;

I have a compressed file on ubuntu, with extention **".cmpr"**,  i need to extract it, and nothing had
worked for me so far, tried unzip, bunzip2 and gunzip, and tar -xv; and also tried everything with
$(file -i archive.cmpr) - the file name is "archive.cmpr, which gives **"application/x-compress"** as mime type.

Can someone please help me found out how to extract this ? (without external software if possible)

### edit: adding file content in hexadecimal:

"

00000000  1f 9d 90 54 d0 a4 99 03  c2 4c 1a 36 65 40 dc 09  |...T.....L.6e@..|
00000010  43 70 cc 9b 36 70 e4 94  99 33 a7 0c 19 05        |Cp..6p...3....|
0000001e

"

(i used hd command for this)

Comment: Please provide the first few bytes in hexadecimal.

Comment: Edied above, see changes

Answer (score 1):

This is using simple LZW compression, which was the most widely used compression algorithm on Unix and Unix-like systems prior to gzip.  You should be able to uncompress it using the old `uncompress` program from the [ncompress](https://vapier.github.io/ncompress/) package, which has been around since the 1980s, or using gunzip since it also includes support for this older format.  However the normal file extension is `.Z`; it won't recognize `.cmpr`.  You can either rename the file or use a command like `gunzip <archive.cmpr >archive.out`.